# Firefox in kiosk mode is able to close with touchscreen gesture

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, gnome

I want to run websites on a kiosk setup with only a touchscreen. I’m using Gnome (for the virtual keyboard) and I use the Firefox V92.0 browser. When a website is opened, I can make a gesture from top to bottom to minimize Firefox. Is there any setting I can adjust, so it will not happen?

Kind regards,
Kelvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I download this Gnome extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1140/disable-gestures/

And I followed this tutorial:
https://superuser.com/questions/1542018/how-to-disable-close-fullscreen-touchscreen-gesture-on-gnome-fedora

The cursor issue is fixed by downloading and installing 'unclutter' with the following command.

```
apt-get install unclutter
```

After that, I added unclutter as a start-up program in the background.